# It is the power set of $\Bbb R$ a topology of $\Bbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

Maybe this is a very easy question of topology but I dont have all things clear.

The question is: the whole power set of $\Bbb R$ is a topology of $\Bbb R$ or not?

The axioms to define a topology $\tau$ in a set X are:

1. $\emptyset,\ X \in \tau$
2. Every finite intersection of elements of $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$ too
3. Every union of elements of $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$ too

If $\mathscr P(\Bbb R)=\tau \ $ I cant see a way where axioms dont hold but this means that all subsets of $\Bbb R$ are open and closed.

It is correct my reasoning or this is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it’s a topology on $\Bbb R$, and yes, every subset of $\Bbb R$ is both open and closed in this topology. It’s called the *discrete topology* on $\Bbb R$. You can replace $\Bbb R$ by any set.

Comment: Oh, yes... the discrete one. Ty very much @Brian

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the largest topology on $\mathbb R $: every set is open (and thus every set is closed). In this topology, any function $f:\mathbb R\to T $, for any topological space $T $, is continuous.

The other extreme is the topology $\{\mathbb R,\emptyset\} $, in which no nontrivial set is open, and so the only continuous functions are the constants.

Comment: Ty... I just get slightly confused because I had related in my mind discrete topology to things as natural numbers... it is a bit counter-intuitive think in the continuum real line as discrete points.

Comment: @Masacroso don't get trapped into thinking mathematical objects have to somehow coincide with something observable. I hear philosophers call "the continuum" "nonsense" because it is infinite and infinitely divisible, when in fact the rational numbers also form an infinite set that's infinitely divisible topologically, so I guess we should throw those out too. You know what? I've never *seen* a negative number...

Comment: Is every function continuous because the inverse image of any open set is always open because ALL sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is open in this topology?  Why is every set also closed?

Comment: Yes. And every set is closed because its complement is open.